# unrecognized selector sent to instance when trying to retrieve string value

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a NSMutablearray wich contain NSArrays(each array contain int and String values).
When i try to retrieve and display the data from the first array:
That was ok with the int value, it was displayed correctly.

```
    NSLog(@"%i",[[[lesQuestions objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] intValue]);
```

But when i try to display the String value:

```
    NSLog(@"%@",[[[lesQuestions objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1] stringValue]);
```

I got exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I am definitely sure that the int value is the first item (index 0) and the String value is the second (index 1).
When i log the MutableArray which holds the NSArrays, i got the values correctly, so the problem is on the reference of the item i guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The object in your array is already an NSString, so the call to stringValue is unnecessary. NSString doesn't implement a method called stringValue, hence the exception you're seeing. Just do this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[lesQuestions objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1]);
```

`-intValue` is a method implemented by NSNumber, to get an integer primitive out of the NSNumber instance, and your use of `intValue` is correct assuming the first object in the array is an NSNumber (or an NSString, which also implements `-intValue`).

All that said, I don't generally think it's a great idea to store instances of different classes in the same array like you're doing. You'd probably be better off using an NSDictionary where each value is stored with a unique key, say `@"index"` for the number and `@"name"` for the string.

Answer (score 1):

NSLog respectively the ability of standard objects do display themselfs is more powerful than you may think.

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[[lesQuestions objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]);
 NSLog(@"%@",[[lesQuestions objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1]);
```

You could even find this useful unless you have a really high number of array elements:

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[lesQuestions objectAtIndex:0]);
```

or

```
 NSLog(@"%@",lesQuestions);
```

Give it a try!